Pullback of two split monomorphisms in an abelian category
$\require{AMScd}$ Let $i_A : A \to M$ and $i_B : B \to M$ be two split monomorphisms in an abelian category. Consider the following pullback:
$$\begin{CD}
P @>j_A>> A\\
@VVj_BV @VVi_AV\\
B @>i_B>> M
\end{CD}$$
Question: Are $j_A$ and $j_B$ also split monomorphisms?
If required, let us specify the abelian category to be $\mathbb{C}$-linear.

Not necessarily.
In the category of abelian groups, let $M=\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, and let $A$ and $B$ be the cyclic subgroups generated by $(1,0)$ and $(1,2)$, with $i_A$ and $i_B$ the inclusion maps. Then $P$ is the cyclic subgroup generated by $(2,0)$, which is not a retract of $A$ or $B$.
This can be adapted to give a $\mathbb{C}$-linear example, by taking the category of $\mathbb{C}[t]$-modules, with $M=\mathbb{C}[t]/(t^2)\times\mathbb{C}[t]/(t^2)$, and $A$ and $B$ the submodules generated by $(1,0)$ and $(1,t)$.
